# could not launch process: can not run under Rosetta, check that the installed build of Go is right for your CPU architecture

Tags: go, debugging, goland

I have mac with M2, The build passes successfully, yet when I run in a debug mode in goland I get this error:

could not launch process: can not run under Rosetta, check that the installed build of Go is right for your CPU architecture

any help please
Thank you

Comment: Download Go for arm64 architecture and it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your Intellij version is not compatible with your macbook architecture, try downloading a version for M2 laptop